# Como faço pra fazer uma div começar oculta?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho uma function aqui que faz com que a div fique invisivel e visivel, mas ela começa visivel, gostaria que começasse invisivel.

Comment: Como eh sua function e sua div? mas `display: none` torna um elemento invisivel

Comment: essa é a function, function Mudarestado(el,g) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    //inserir variaveis estado_onibus, destino para o arquivo enviodeerro.php

    }

Comment: Pode usar só CSS para resolver isso! Quer um exemplo?

Comment: [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function mostra_oculta(){

    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

```html
<div id='myDIV' style='background-color: green;'><p>Aqui a div</p></div>

<button type='button' id='btnMO' onclick='mostra_oculta()'>Mostra/Oculta</button>
```

Sem nenhum segredo, basta apenas colocar este código na sua div:

```
display: none;
```

Este é um exemplo da sua div:

```
<div style='display: none;'><p>Div do gustavo aqui</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

visto que estás a manipular a propriedade css `display` para começares com o elemento 'invisível' basta acrescentar nas propriedades css desse elemento:

```
display:none
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção apenas com CSS só para constar caso não queira usar o JavaScript

```css
div {
    display: none;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="btn">Clique no Checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="btn">
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Siga este exemplo basico:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <label>Título</label>
    <input type="text" value="texto">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo de como iniciar um elemento invisível e alternar sua propriedade de acordo com uma função no javascript.

```js
function magica(){
  var $element = document.getElementById("luz");
  var $button = document.getElementById("switch");
  
  if ($element.hasAttribute("active")) {
    $element.removeAttribute("active")
    $element.style.display = "none";
    $button.innerText = "Luz!";
  }
  else {
    $element.setAttribute("active", "true")
    $element.style.display = "block";
    $button.innerText = "Noite!";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#luz {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<button id="switch" onclick="magica()">Luz!</button>
<div id="luz"></div>
```